# Class java.beans.Beans can not access a member of class Perosn.PersonDAO with modifiers ""?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have jsp file saveperson.jsp which uses StudentDAO.java file as a java Bean, but this not work properly..... 
Please suggest me where I am getting wrong..

I am getting following error in the browser...

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   class Perosn.PersonDAO : java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   java.beans.Beans can not access a member of class Perosn.PersonDAO
>   with modifiers ""

saveperson.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="Perosn.*"%>


<html>

    <body>

         <jsp:useBean id="pDAO" class="Perosn.PersonDAO" scope = "page" /> 

         <jsp:useBean id="personBean" class="Perosn.PersonInfo" scope = "page" /> 
        <jsp:setProperty name="personBean" property="*" />


        <%
         pDAO.setPerson(personBean);

        %>

        <center>
        <h1>You have successfully add the record!</h1>
        <h4>  
              <a href="index.html" > Add another Person Record </a> <br>
              <br><br>


              <a href="searchperson.jsp" > Search Person </a>    
          </h4> 
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

PersonDAO.java

```
import java.util.*;

import java.sql.*;

import java.io.*;

public class PersonDAO implements Serializable  {

    private Connection conn;

    private PreparedStatement stmt;

    public ArrayList pList;

    PersonDAO() throws SQLException{

        establishConnection();
    }
    public void establishConnection() throws SQLException

    {

        String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Asim Iqbal\\Documents\\PersonInfo.accdb";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }
    public ArrayList getPerson(String name) throws SQLException {     

        pList=new ArrayList();

        String sql="SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name=?";

        stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1,name);

        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

         String add,n;

         String p;

        while(rs.next()){

            n=rs.getString("Name");

            add=rs.getString("Address");

            p=rs.getString("PhoneNumber");

            PersonInfo pInfo=new PersonInfo();

            pInfo.setName(n);

            pInfo.setAddress(add);

            pInfo.setpNumber(p);

            pList.add(pInfo);
        }
        return pList;

}

   public  void setPerson(PersonInfo person) throws SQLException{

   String sql = " INSERT INTO Person VALUES (?, ?, ?)";  

   PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  

   String name = person.getName();   

   String add = person.getAddress(); 

   String p = person.getpNumber(); 

   pStmt.setString(1,name);

   pStmt.setString(2,add);

   pStmt.setString(3,p);

   pStmt.executeUpdate();

   if(conn!=null){

       conn.close();
   }

   }
}
```

PersonInfo.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class PersonInfo implements Serializable {

  private  String name,address;

   private String pNumber;

    public void setName(String n){

        name=n;

}
    public void setpNumber(String pn){

        pNumber=pn;
    }
   public void setAddress(String ad){

       address=ad;
   }
   public String getName(){

       return name;
   }
   public String getpNumber(){

       return pNumber;
   }
   public String getAddress(){

          return address;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misspelling in the import and class parameter in the following lines:

```
<%@page import="Perosn.*"%>

<jsp:useBean id="pDAO" class="Perosn.PersonDAO" scope = "page" /> 

<jsp:useBean id="personBean" class="Perosn.PersonInfo" scope = "page" />
```

Change "Perosn" to "Person".

Comment: Yes, change "Perosn" to "Person".